# Is it normal for sys.tracebacklimit to impact all modules in a program, not just one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

In order to improve customer visbility I incorporated `sys.tracebacklimit = 0` during  initialization to reduce customer facing traceback stack trace.

Now due to this change, it has stopped printing error tracebacks for all the packages consuming my python client.

Is this an expected behaviour?

In order to mitigate we removed that those lines but I am still very unclear on how does a traceback change only supposed to be run in the my package can affect all packages together?

Comment: _only supposed to be run in the my package_ you update `sys` module value, not your package.

Comment: Yes, it's expected. This is a global setting for the entire program.

Comment: There's only one copy of each module. When you `import` something any other part of your program imported, you're getting a reference to the global copy from the cache. Thus, there's only one copy of `sys`, and only one value for `sys.tracebacklimit`.

Comment: This makes sense now. Is this documented somewhere in the python documentation or just common knowledge?